# Usage of implicit differentiation in this case

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I have been doing one exercise problem, and there is something unclear about it. Namely, the 1st approach and its solution are clear, but the implicit way is unclear. I am uncertain how did they get the equations marked by the red rectangle, how did they get it by using implicit differentiation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compute the derivative of $x\left(r, \theta\right)=r\cos\theta$ with respect to $\theta$ (treating left-hand side as an independent variable, not as a function depending on $\theta$):

- First, let us differentiate polar form expression for $x$ with respect to $y$:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
    x&=r\cos\theta & \implies && 
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[x\right] &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} 
    \left[r\cos\theta\right] 
    = \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y}\cos\theta -r\sin\theta \cdot \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}
    \\  && &&
      \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y} &= r_y\cos\theta - r\sin\theta\cdot \theta_y
    \\ &&  &&
      0 &= r_y\cos\theta - r\sin\theta\cdot\theta_y 
  \\ && \implies  &&
      &\boxed{\theta_y = \dfrac{r_y\cos\theta}{r\sin\theta}=\dfrac{\frac{r_y}{r}x}{y} = \dfrac{r_y}{r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{y}}
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Second, differentiate $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ with respect to $y$:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
    r^2 &= x^2+y^2 &\implies &&\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}
    \left[r^2 \right]&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[x^2+y^2\right] = 2\cdot 0 + 2y
    \\  && &&
      2rr_y &= 0+2y
    \\ &&\implies &&
    &\boxed{r_y = \dfrac{y}{r}}
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Third, combine two above results with the formula $x^2+y^2=r^2$ to get the final answer:

$$
\theta_y = \dfrac{r_y}{r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{\frac{y}{r}}{r}\cdot\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{x}{r^2}
$$

Thus we finally get

$$
 \boxed{\theta_y = \dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}}
$$
$\hspace{64ex}$*Q.E.D.*